# MySQL Запрос Many To Many

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql

Можно ли составить такой запрос к БД, если да то не могу придумать как.
Собственно что нужно выбрать:

Есть 2 таблицы со связью многие ко многим.
Допустим 1 - просто записи (post), 2 - категории (category), ну и 3 - таблица связей (post_category).

Есть массив id из category, нужно выбрать все записи post, которые связаны со всеми категориями, перечисленными в этом массиве с id категорий.

Собственно вопрос в том, можно ли это сделать как-то одним запросом? Или может выбрать те записи, которые связаны хотя бы с одной из категорий и потом уже программно фильтровать результат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ae21/4).

Смысл в том, что совпадений по категории у поста должно быть ровно столько, сколько категорий. Если длина списка 2, значит having count... = 2, если длина списка 3, значит ...=3 и т.д.

ЗЫ И снова спасибо [@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh) за схему!

Comment: Оу! Спасибо, не вчитывался в Ваш пример, так как уже сам пришел к такому же решению

Внятно прочитав:
http://www.mysql.ru/docs/gruber/mg13.html 
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_relational_division.html
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_exists_predicate.html
http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_using_any_all_keywords_with_comparison_predicates.html

И вот что получилось:

SELECT jt1.id_post, jt1.id_category, COUNT( jt1.id_post ) 
FROM post_category jt1
WHERE id_category
IN ( 4, 36 ) 
GROUP BY jt1.id_post
HAVING COUNT( jt1.id_post ) = 2

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, название вашей проблемы - [реляционное деление](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_relational_division.html). Соответственно, имеются разные алгоритмы решения. Выбирайте.